# Hashes won't match

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js

I took a few code snippets from that repo https://github.com/DanialK/PassportJS-Authentication , and adapted it so instead of using MongoDB I'm using MySQL. This is my code to check the password:

```
User.checkPassword = function(username, password, done) {
        pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
                connection.query("SELECT * FROM " + userTable + " WHERE username=? LIMIT 1;",[username], function(err, user){
                        // if(err) throw err;
                        if(err) return done(err);
                        if(!user[0]){
                                console.log("Incorrect User")
                                return done(null, false, { message : 'Incorrect Username.' });
                        }
                        user = user[0];
                        hash(password, user.salt, function(err, hash){
                                hash = hash.toString("hex");
                                if(err) return done(err);
                                if(hash == user.hash){
                                        console.log("SUCCESS!");
                                        return done(null, user);
                                }
                                done(null, false, {
                                        message : 'Incorrect password'
                                });
                        });
                });
        });
};
```

The MySQL field to store the hash is varchar(128), and before adding the hash to the table I  use toString('hex') in the buffer to store it. The hash is made with https://github.com/visionmedia/node-pwd . My code look a lot like the tutorial's code but for MySQL.  But when I try to compare the passwords, the hashes aren't equal. Why's that?
Here's the code that I use to register an user:

```
User.cadastrar = function(username,password,done){
    var User = this;
    hash(password, function(err, salt, hash){
        hash = hash.toString('hex');
        if(err) throw err;
        // if (err) return done(err);
        pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
            connection.query("INSERT INTO " + userTable + " (username,salt,hash) VALUES (?,?,?);", [username,salt,hash], function(err, user){
                if(err) throw err;
                // if (err) return done(err);
                connection.query("SELECT * FROM " + userTable + " WHERE username=? LIMIT 1;",[username], function(err,user){
                    done(null, user[0]);
                });
            });
            connection.release();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add code where you save password to database.

Comment: I added it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: can you add some basic debugging with `console.log` when you compare the hash for passwords?

Comment: Yes. Here is the print-screen of the console:  
http://prntscr.com/36o3v5

Comment: Sorry. I noticed my mistake. The bytesize of the hash was 128 and it generated a 256 chars string, and I was using varchar(128) in the hash field(MySQL)